# og:image not detected by facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have seen a lot of scenario where my og:image were not detected (url problem, bad og tags, ssl certificate corrupted, etc.) but I'm quite lost right now as to why this one is not detected by Facebook.

The URL is :

https://remax2001.com/en/our-properties/chomedey-laval/3855-boul-de-chenonceau/11350244?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social_automatic&utm_campaign=Centiva&social_id=48888

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

EDIT:

Like @wlarcheveque I was able to see the image with a VPN. Also with my cellphone I don't see the image if I'm on the Wifi of the office but I can see it with the mobile data... The problem was identified by a client who is not on the same LAN as me so I'm not sure what is happening here...

Comment: Looks like it is detected https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fremax2001.com%2Fen%2Four-properties%2Fchomedey-laval%2F3855-boul-de-chenonceau%2F11350244%3Futm_source%3Dtwitter%26utm_medium%3Dsocial_automatic%26utm_campaign%3DCentiva%26social_id%3D48888

Comment: It's showing blank in the debugger for me and was shared blank by a client too...

Comment: works fine for me too

Comment: Does not work on my side. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RoecafSxBjKz7LdKTjdBpC6DvqM3n30W

Comment: I tried using a VPN (Detroit) and the image shows in Facebook debugger. That is an odd issue.